# DocuSign: How do I send the values of the Document Custom Fields (aka tab definitions) while creating an envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I need some help to identify how to send Document Custom Fields' values at the stage of creating an envelope. Below is the workflow:

1. Create the Document Custom Fields (account specific) with name, type and initial value through API (POST [BaseURI]/tab_definitions)
2. Create a template with document through API and place the required Document Custom Fields in the document through DocuSign UI
3. Create an envelope and send specific values for the Document Custom Fields through API (POST [BaseURI]/envelopes)

Creating an envelope is working fine referring (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create). I have tried sending the values through:

- document -> documentFields
- customFields -> textCustomFields

```
{
    "templateId": "51234567-1244-1234-1234-12345a857203",
    "templateRoles": [
            {
                "roleName": "Role1",
                "name": "Jane Doe",
                "email": "jane@doe.com"
            },
            {
                "roleName": "Role2",
                "name": "John Doe",
                "email": "john@doe.com"
            }
    ],
    "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [
            {
                "name": "Account.Name",
                "value": "account-name1234"
            },
            {
                "name": "Candidate.FullName",
                "value": "candidate-name1234"
            },
            {
                "name": "Candidate.Mobile",
                "value": "0412345678"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CustomFields parameter is for *Envelope* Custom Fields. If you want to define tag values for a recipient, the tag parameters should be nested under the TemplateRole. You'll also want to use the `tabLabel` parameter to identify tabs instead of the `name`. Finally, make sure your Role Names and TabLabels match exactly between your template and your API call. Try this:

```
{
    "templateId": "51234567-1244-1234-1234-12345a857203",
    "templateRoles": [
            {
                "roleName": "Role1",
                "name": "Jane Doe",
                "email": "jane@doe.com"
                "tabs": {
                    "TextTabs": [
                        {
                        "tabLabel": "Account.Number",
                        "value": "00000000"
                        },
                        {
                        "tabLabel": "Account.Name",
                        "value":"ExampleAccount"
                        }
                    ],
            },
            {
                "roleName": "Role2",
                "name": "John Doe",
                "email": "john@doe.com"
            }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Finally, you may want to consider using a Composite Template instead of the basic Envelope Creation call. Details as to why are available here: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates/

Comment: Thank you. This works for the particular signer. Is there a way to add the custom fields for all signers of the document in the template and not a particular signer?

Comment: Add each signer's tags under their individual definition.